# Painting a black square

Tags: java

I'm trying to repaint a black square across the panel, and when it reaches 400 pixel it goes to the next row, but the problem is, the first block of black square does not start at x equals to 0. It starts at x equals to 1 for some reason. The rest of the rows starts at 0. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

```
package events;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Paint extends JPanel {

int x = 0;
int y = 0;

static Paint g = new Paint();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    int r1 = Use.rand(0, 255); //My own Use.rand method which returns a random number
    int g1 = Use.rand(0, 255);
    int b1 = Use.rand(0, 255);
    Color color = new Color(0, 0, 0);
    g.setColor(color);

    if (x == 400) {
        x = 0;
        y += 50;
    }
    int i1 = x;
    int i2 = y;
    int i3 = 50;
    int i4 = 50;
    g.fill3DRect(i1, i2, i3, i4, true);
    x++;

    repaint();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Paint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Make sure you're adding the component correctly. Try painting all of the panel red before you do the black square, and see if the empty row you're talking about is red or white - If it's red then it's a problem with the actual square drawing, if it's white then the panel isn't being added correctly

Comment: an easy solution is to set x=-2 for the First time(only).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You *must* call `super.paintComponent(g)` at the beginning of your paintComponent method.
2. Remove the call to `repaint()` and remove the sleep.  Neither of those should ever be called in a paint method under any circumstances.
3. You don't get to control when a component is painted.  The system controls it.  Paint requests can happen for a number of reasons, and often your code will be painting just part of the component (in which case, the Graphics object's clip may be set before your method is called).  Since you may be doing a partial paint, changing the values used for painting may only take effect in part of the component;  the effect will look like garbage.  You cannot rely on the invocation of `paintComponent` to trigger your changing of your values.  Consider doing that in a [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead, and calling `repaint()` in the Timer task.

You will probably find the [custom painting tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and the [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) article informative.

Comment: ... +1 for excellent points - the program is very badly designed  and constructed but it doesn't actually answer OP's question... His code does run - he wants to know why the first block starts at pixel 1 rather than 0 and how that could be fixed.

Comment: I think I addressed it, though perhaps not as directly as I should have.  Changing x (and y) needs to be done outside of the paint method.  It's entirely possible, even likely, that x was changed but the change was not seen, due to a partial paint.

Comment: Yes you're right. I did some messing about with the code and it is a simple case that paintComponent is carrying out x++ before if paints the square. I presume that this is because it passes the instruction to  paint over to the Graphics object , and that does the painting, after the paint component function has already completed and x has already been incremented.

Comment: Well, that's weird...How come it works if x is initialized to -2, but it doesn't work if it's initialized to -1? Even if it increases by 1 before painting it, shouldn't -1+1=0, and so shouldn't it start at pixel zero anyway?

Comment: Because the frequency with which paintComponent is called is complex and hard to predict.  Your component may be painted in "stripes"—separate wide, flat rectangles (like 0,0,200,50 then 0,50,200,50 then 0,100,200,50 etc.).  That's just one possibility.  It's highly dependent on the platform and video driver.  You can't go by what "seems to work," because it will be different every time you run.